# Monotouch EKEvent Notes not being saved

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, eventkit

What am I doing wrong here? currentEvent.Title prints correctly. currentEvent.Notes is always blank..

```
public void CalendarEvents()
{
   EKEventStore store = new EKEventStore();
   EKCalendar calendar = store.DefaultCalendarForNewEvents;

   // Query the event
   if (calendar != null)
   {
     // Add a new event
     EKEvent newEvent = EKEvent.FromStore(store);
     newEvent.Title = "Lunch at McDonalds";
     newEvent.Calendar = calendar;
     newEvent.StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
     newEvent.EndDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(4);
     newEvent.Availability = EKEventAvailability.Free;
     newEvent.Notes = "hello";
     store.SaveEvent(newEvent, EKSpan.ThisEvent, new IntPtr());

   // Searches for every event in the next year
   NSPredicate predicate = store.PredicateForEvents(NSDate.Now,DateTime.Now.AddDays(360),new EKCalendar[] {calendar});

   store.EnumerateEvents(predicate, delegate(EKEvent currentEvent, ref bool stop)
   {
       // Perform your check for an event type
       Console.WriteLine(currentEvent.Title);
       Console.WriteLine(currentEvent.Notes);
   });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The API likely has changed because the above won't compile 'as-is'. So I updated your:

```
 store.SaveEvent(newEvent, EKSpan.ThisEvent, new IntPtr());
```

to

```
 NSError error;
 store.SaveEvent(newEvent, EKSpan.ThisEvent, out error);
```

Otherwise, using the latest MonoTouch, I get both strings displayed in the "Application Output" (app running on device).

```
 Lunch at McDonalds
 hello
```

Maybe that was fixed when the API was modified ?